# Vary Data Set Parameter by Chart

Tags: reporting-services, ssrs-2008

I fear I am missing something very obvious here, but I am new to reporting services.

I have a dataset that calls a stored procedure with a number of parameters. I want to create a number of graphs that all get data from the same dataset, but vary one or more of the parameters when doing so, however I cannot seem to find a way to do this, any ideas?

Answer (score 2):

Each DataSet is only populated once when the report is loaded.

You have a couple of options I can see:

- Have multiple DataSets which call the same underlying SP but pass different parameters each time.
- Call the DataSet once to populate all the required report data, then
  for each Chart apply different Filters, which can be parameter-based
  as required.

[image]

I would say option 2, i.e. just applying chart-level filters to the DataSet, should be able to fulfil your requirements.